# ngx-bootstrap datetimepicker not able to set data

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, angularjs-directive

I have used ngx-bootstrap datepicker in my web application two days before it was in working phase but don't know why it is not working properly.
I my getting date successfully but not able to set it properly in input field.

I am using reactive form approach.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="require" for="input-required">Pre-sale start date</label>
     <input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" #dp="bsDatepicker" bsDatepicker [(bsValue)]="bsValue1"
      data-provide="datepicker" [bsConfig]="bsConfig" #startDate  [maxDate]= "maxPreSaleStartDate" (bsValueChange)="onPreSaleStartDate(bsValue1)" 
      id="presale_start" formControlName="presale_start">
       <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="errPreSaleStartDateRequired">
               Please select pre-sale start date
      </small>
</div>
```

Component code:-

```
onPreSaleStartDate(date) {

        if (date == null && this.xyzForm.get(['presale_start']).value != null) {
          this.errPreSaleStartDateRequired = true;
        }
        else {
          this.preSaleEndDate = new Date();
          this.preSaleEndDate.setDate(date.getDate()+1);
          this.errPreSaleStartDateRequired = false;
        }
      }
```

I am getting this presale_start:- "2018-02-01T07:15:50.000Z". I am setting value and calling restful API it is setting in backend successfully but when i get the value it shows Invalid date in HTML.

Help needed

Comment: Try `<input type="date" ...` for a start.

Comment: @FDavidov didnt work for me

Comment: Can you catch and share what you are getting that causes the HTML error, along with the error message?